# How to Remove a specific Img tag from string

Tags: html, vb.net

***Using visual basic***

I have a string that contains HTML inside of it. There may be many img tags inside of it, but there is an img tag with a specific alt attribute that I want to remove.

How do I remove the entire img tag from the string if it contains 'badImage' as the alt attribute? I still want to keep any other img tags that may be inside the string.

```
Dim myString as string = "<html><body><span>some text here..</span><img src='#' alt='goodImage'/><span>more text...</span><img src='#' alt='badImage'/></body></html>
```

I have the following code so far, but it removes ALL img tags from the string, whereas I only want to remove the img tag with the 'badImage' alt attribute. Is this possible?

```
Dim imgRegex As New Regex("<img[^>]*>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
myString = myString.Replace(bodyContent, "")
```

Please answer in VB.Net. Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: E.g., `dim include = "badImage"` -> `$"<img[^<]+(?:{include})[^>]+>"`, `dim include = "badImage|goodImage"` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping that the html source is a well-formatted html/xml/[whatever markup language], you can remove bad tags by using `XmlDocument` to read your source then remove bad elements detect them  by “`alt`” attribute.
A little code demonstration:

```
Function ClearBadImgTags(source As String) As String
    Dim xDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
    Try

        xDoc.LoadXml(source)
        Dim badImgs As IEnumerable(Of XmlElement) = From el In xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("img")
                                                    Select img = CType(el, XmlElement)
                                                    Where img.HasAttribute("alt") AndAlso img.Attributes("alt").Value = "badImage"

        For i As Integer = 0 To badImgs.Count - 1 : badImgs(i).ParentNode.RemoveChild(badImgs(i)) : Next
        Return xDoc.OuterXml

    Catch ex As Exception
        Stop 'Bad XML or something go wrong
    End Try

    Return ""

End Function
```

Then:

```
Dim myString As String = "<html><body><span>some text here..</span><img src='#' alt='goodImage'/><span>more text...</span><img src='#' alt='badImage'/></body></html>"
Dim newString As String = ClearBadImgTags(myString)
```

Comment: This is very helpful in assisting what I need to achieve! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that resolves your issue :). You're welcome